# Is there a way to do a poll and offer in DelayQueue in synchronized way?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, blockingqueue

In my implementation I use `DelayQueue` to prevent too many concurrent access of my method. I found that `DelayQueue` use internal `lock` on both methods `poll` and `offer`, but in my case I need to do something like this:

```
if(Objects.nonNull(delayQueue.poll())) {
   delayQueue.offer(...);
}
```

And those few lines of code are not atomic right? I can add my own `ReentrantLock` and do something like:

```
try {
   lock.lock();
   if(poll()) {
      offer(...)
   }
finally {
   lock.unlock();
}
```

But it looks redundant for me as we have now 2 internal calls to `lock/unlock` and one external.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: What is your code supposed to do? `DelayQueue` might not be the right choice.

Comment: Besides, that code **is** thread-safe. What it isn't is *atomic*. Do you need it to be atomic?

Comment: I have 10 predefined elements in the queue and after I poll them I want to add them back in 10 seconds. Actually it a kind of limiter to prevent too many concurrent accesses to my method

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Surely your program has nobler purposes than adding things to a queue forever.

Comment: @Kayaman I've edited my question

Comment: Okay, so what you want is *throttling*. If you're not opposed to using frameworks, [RateLimiter](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html) would be exactly what you need. A simple `Semaphore` would work if you don't care about the rate, just the amount of concurrent access.

Comment: Actually yes RateLimiter would be ideal for me, but I found that it works in a way that "requests being smoothly spread over each second" and in case all calls would be done in first 10ms it would block all of them except one. In other words I don't wont to have them smoothly spread I wont to have exact number of calls per second no matter when

Comment: So wouldn't a simple semaphore work then? Provided that your threads can keep up.